# What's the meaning of "biased"?

Tags: translation

in a reporter in NME magazine have a question "Are you biased?". This reporter talk about race and problems about racism.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bias is simply favoritism or prejudice based on some preexisting condition. The implication in the article you read is that the listener (whomever the reporter is talking to) has an inclination to side with one side or the other probably because they're of one race and not recognizing issues of the other race.

For example, if I say that "Sony is the best TV brand on the market" and I work at Sony, people may call me biased. I work there, I like their products and I favor them simply because I work there. That's me being biased towards Sony or biased against other companies.

Answer (score 0):

Biased (towards/against/in favour of somebody or something, means having or showing a bias : having or showing an unfair tendency to believe that some people, ideas, etc., are better than others
Examples of BIASED
She is too biased to speak about the case objectively.
He is biased against women.
He gave me biased information about the incident. 
The jury was biased towards him due his colour and sentenced him to twenty years of imprisonment.